# Saving Local Application Settings

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to safely retain/save data (settings) other than IndexedDB and manual saving (prompt the user with a dialog box to save)?

Basically I am writing an offline application and will be bundled and deployed as a local html file (e.g. file:///D:/test/index.html, no servers, just run by double-clicking the html file). It will have some settings and I need to be able to save these settings locally. The first time the app boots up, I retrieve the settings from a `app-settings.json` file and save it to IndexedDB.

However, my problem is that when the user clears the browser data, the settings will be deleted as well.

I do not want to prompt the user with a dialog box asking to save the `app-settings.json` everytime an update is made to the settings. (It would also be prone to duplicate, misplaced settings)

Any suggestion on how to go about this? How can I safely retain the application settings without any servers? Maybe there is an offline database of some sort that can be used in scenarios like this?

Would appreciate any help here! I'm desperately out of ideas :(

Thank you!

Comment: _"my problem is that when the user clears the browser data, the settings will be deleted as well."_ - that is what we call "works as designed." _"How can I safely retain the application settings without any servers?"_ - I don't see any way you could; _anything_ stored in the browser in one of the various ways (cookies, localstorage, databases) will get removed, when the user clears their data for that specific storage mechanism.

Comment: JavaScript in browsers can't access local filesystem without user's interaction. Also, local HTML files using file protocol are much outdated. What is the additional information in this question compared to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71249894/overwrite-json-file-from-the-browser-silently-html)?

Comment: @Teemu - prev question was specifically asking about writing locally, silently. My question here is if there is any other way to handle the cached settings. Maybe there is a different local database that can be used or something.. I think all I've seen require connectivity to servers :(

Comment: The only way to circumvent the browser's restrictions is to not run it in a browser. Hosting the app with Electron would allow you to circumvent the file system restrictions.

Comment: Actually ... When I clear the browser data, I'd expect everything really being gone, if something was left (without specifically granting it) I'd consider that as malicious behavior. If your users want to clear their browser, why not let them?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Check if site's storage has been marked as persistent
if (navigator.storage && navigator.storage.persist) {
  const isPersisted = await navigator.storage.persisted();
  console.log(`Persisted storage granted: ${isPersisted}`);
}
```

please enable persistent storage by enabling navigator.storage.persist, and I would suggest start using service workers to manage offline applications.

https://web.dev/persistent-storage/
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers

Comment: I believe persistent data still get deleted when clearing browser data

Comment: Use Service Worker's storage API — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache — a global object on the service worker that allows us to store assets delivered by responses, and keyed by their requests. This API works in a similar way to the browser's standard cache, but it is specific to your domain. It persists until you tell it not to — again, you have full control.

Answer (score -2):

**You Can use the
Use the Javascript File Api**
*https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API*

The dialog to save the file will be shown once,
Then reading the file will not require a file dialog.

**BTW**

**VS Code** web also uses the api: https://vscode.dev/

Comment: LocalStorage - I will have the same problem I have with IndexedDB. As for FileAPI, then there would be a user dialog box, which is something we do not want.

Comment: This should be a comment. Please wait until you have the required reputation#

Comment: Only for one time while writing the file but not when reading it. VsCode web also uses it: https://vscode.dev/